# What is the Tomcat installation directory?

Tags: tomcat

Based [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseWTP/article.html) I'm trying to setup Tomcat Server, I have successfully installed it and tested it. Then I stopped it as recommended in the tutorial. I'm setting up "New Server Runtime Environment" as you can see under Tomcat Installation Directory is a windows directory, anyone knows the Ubuntu directory equivalent for this? Thanks.

Comment: Apparently I don't have the rep here to answer, but for me on Ubuntu 18 it is in /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.50

Answer (score 121):

There are three important directories for Tomcat:

- `/etc/tomcat{X}` for configuration
- `/usr/share/tomcat{X}` for runtime, called CATALINA_HOME
- `/usr/share/tomcat{X}-root` for webapps

The *alternative* path to Tomcat, called CATALINA_BASE, is `/var/lib/tomcat{X}`

The temp folder for Tomcat is `/tmp/tomcat{X}-tomcat{X}-tmp`

All the above paths work for Tomcat 6, 7, and 8. Replace `{X}` with the appropriate Tomcat major version number, e.g. `/etc/tomcat8`.

Comment: Still applies to tomcat 8

Comment: What's the difference in the first two paths? They seem identical to me!

Comment: @gsamaras I believe the second path should be `/usr/share/tomcat{X}`, as this contains the runtime files (`bin` and `lib`). I'll propose an edit.

Comment: How come this doesn't appear in the Tomcat documentation?!

Comment: @pHCito because tomcat does not do the installation it is ubuntu

Comment: I have tomcat running on my ubuntu 18 vm (hitting localhost 8080 proves that), but I can't find tomcat at any of the above locations.  Where else might it be?

Comment: Strangely though, the designated home-directory for the `tomcat` user appears to be `/var/lib/tomcat` - which does not exist. Shouldn't they have made it to be `/var/lib/tomcat{X}`?

Answer (score 62):

After installing Tomcat with `apt-get` on Ubuntu 12.04, Tomcat creates and uses these directories:

**/etc/tomcat6/**

```
/etc/tomcat6/
├── Catalina
│   └── localhost
│       ├── ROOT.xml
│       └── solr.xml -> ../../../solr/solr-tomcat.xml
├── catalina.properties
├── context.xml
├── logging.properties
├── policy.d
│   ├── 01system.policy
│   ├── 02debian.policy
│   ├── 03catalina.policy
│   ├── 04webapps.policy
│   ├── 05solr.policy -> /etc/solr/tomcat.policy
│   └── 50local.policy
├── server.xml
├── tomcat-users.xml
└── web.xml
```

**/usr/share/tomcat6**

```
/usr/share/tomcat6
├── bin
│   ├── bootstrap.jar
│   ├── catalina.sh
│   ├── catalina-tasks.xml
│   ├── digest.sh
│   ├── setclasspath.sh
│   ├── shutdown.sh
│   ├── startup.sh
│   ├── tomcat-juli.jar -> ../../java/tomcat-juli.jar
│   ├── tool-wrapper.sh
│   └── version.sh
├── defaults.md5sum
├── defaults.template
└── lib
    ├── annotations-api.jar -> ../../java/annotations-api-6.0.35.jar
    ├── catalina-ant.jar -> ../../java/catalina-ant-6.0.35.jar
    ├── catalina-ha.jar -> ../../java/catalina-ha-6.0.35.jar
    ├── catalina.jar -> ../../java/catalina-6.0.35.jar
    ├── catalina-tribes.jar -> ../../java/catalina-tribes-6.0.35.jar
    ├── commons-dbcp.jar -> ../../java/commons-dbcp.jar
    ├── commons-pool.jar -> ../../java/commons-pool.jar
    ├── el-api.jar -> ../../java/el-api-2.1.jar
    ├── jasper-el.jar -> ../../java/jasper-el-6.0.35.jar
    ├── jasper.jar -> ../../java/jasper-6.0.35.jar
    ├── jasper-jdt.jar -> ../../java/ecj.jar
    ├── jsp-api.jar -> ../../java/jsp-api-2.1.jar
    ├── servlet-api.jar -> ../../java/servlet-api-2.5.jar
    ├── tomcat-coyote.jar -> ../../java/tomcat-coyote-6.0.35.jar
    ├── tomcat-i18n-es.jar -> ../../java/tomcat-i18n-es-6.0.35.jar
    ├── tomcat-i18n-fr.jar -> ../../java/tomcat-i18n-fr-6.0.35.jar
    └── tomcat-i18n-ja.jar -> ../../java/tomcat-i18n-ja-6.0.35.jar
```

**/usr/share/tomcat6-root/**

```
/usr/share/tomcat6-root/
└── default_root
    ├── index.html
    └── META-INF
        └── context.xml
```

**/usr/share/doc/tomcat6**

```
/usr/share/doc/tomcat6
├── changelog.Debian.gz -> ../libtomcat6-java/changelog.Debian.gz
├── copyright
└── README.Debian.gz -> ../tomcat6-common/README.Debian.gz
```

**/var/cache/tomcat6**

```
/var/cache/tomcat6
├── Catalina
│   └── localhost
│       ├── _
│       └── solr
│           └── org
│               └── apache
│                   └── jsp
│                       ├── admin
│                       │   ├── form_jsp.class
│                       │   ├── form_jsp.java
│                       │   ├── get_002dproperties_jsp.class
│                       │   ├── get_002dproperties_jsp.java
│                       │   ├── index_jsp.class
│                       │   ├── index_jsp.java
│                       │   ├── schema_jsp.class
│                       │   ├── schema_jsp.java
│                       │   ├── stats_jsp.class
│                       │   ├── stats_jsp.java
│                       │   ├── threaddump_jsp.class
│                       │   └── threaddump_jsp.java
│                       ├── index_jsp.class
│                       └── index_jsp.java
└── catalina.policy
```

**/var/lib/tomcat6**

```
/var/lib/tomcat6
├── common
│   └── classes
├── conf -> /etc/tomcat6
├── logs -> ../../log/tomcat6
├── server
│   └── classes
├── shared
│   └── classes
├── webapps
│   └── ROOT
│       ├── index.html
│       └── META-INF
│           └── context.xml
└── work -> ../../cache/tomcat6
```

**/var/log/tomcat6**

```
/var/log/tomcat6
├── catalina.2013-06-28.log
├── catalina.2013-06-30.log
├── catalina.out
├── catalina.out.1.gz
└── localhost.2013-06-28.log
```

**/etc/default**

```
/etc/default
├── tomcat7
```

Comment: Which one of all these folders is the right one to put web-apps in?

Comment: mmmm.... let me think.......... "webapps" ?

Comment: I wonder why it creates so many directories in different places

Comment: What is the purpose of this directory?
/etc/tomcat6/
├── Catalina

Answer (score 11):

If you install Tomcat 7 using apt:

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7
```

Then the webapps are located in `/var/lib/tomcat7`

```
$ tree  /var/lib/tomcat7 -L 2
/var/lib/tomcat7
├── common
│   └── classes
├── conf -> /etc/tomcat7
├── logs -> ../../log/tomcat7
├── server
│   └── classes
├── shared
│   └── classes
├── webapps
│   └── ROOT
└── work -> ../../cache/tomcat7
```

Answer (score 5):

for tomcat 7, if you are working with **Intellij IDE**:

Tomcat Home: `/usr/share/tomcat7`

Tomcat base directory: `/var/lib/tomcat7`

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. 
This is directory is what Intellji Ultimate Editon has been asking for last 3 couple of days.
One problem though: I am getting "permission denied" statement when I run the programming. It says,

"Error running 'Unnamed': Error copying configuration files from /var/lib/tomcat9/conf to /home/pranav/.IntelliJIdea2019.2/system/tomcat/Unnamed_Project101/conf: /var/lib/tomcat9/conf/server.xml (Permission denied) "

Answer (score 4):

This is the default Tomcat home page, that can be found on the local file system at:

```
/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/index.html
```

Answer (score 4):

I installed `tomcat7` via `apt-get`, but its directory was not unlike `tomcat6`.

It was located in `/usr/share/tomcat7`

Answer (score 3):

I have followed the [Vogella tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/ApacheTomcat/article.html) to set up the Tomcat server, and I ran into the same issue. If you had installed tomcat7 using the instructions mentioned in the tutorial, just mention the below path in the Tomcat installation directory field, when setting up the server runtime environment in eclipse

`/usr/share/tomcat7`

When I proceeded with the above path, I faced another issue (Could not load the Tomcat server configuration), for which I executed the below commands in terminal and restarted Eclipse. ([Source](http://oramirez.wordpress.com/2012/02/03/eclipse-with-tomcat-v7-0-in-ubuntu-11-10/))

```
cd /usr/share/tomcat7
sudo ln -s /var/lib/tomcat7/conf conf
sudo ln -s /etc/tomcat7/policy.d/03catalina.policy conf/catalina.policy
sudo ln -s /var/log/tomcat7 logs
sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/share/tomcat7/conf
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your are installing Tomcat 6, it will be at:

`/usr/share/tomcat6`

Answer (score 1):

Simple, use linux `find` tool, (you might need to find as `sudo` user)

```
sudo find / -name tomcat7
/etc/logrotate.d/tomcat7
/etc/default/tomcat7
/etc/tomcat7
/etc/init.d/tomcat7
/etc/cron.daily/tomcat7
/usr/share/doc-base/tomcat7
/usr/share/tomcat7
/usr/share/doc/tomcat7
/var/lib/doc-base/documents/tomcat7
/var/lib/tomcat7
/var/cache/tomcat7
/var/log/tomcat7
```

I always forget where's the `webapps` is while deploying the war, this is my command,

```
sudo find / -name webapps
/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps
/home/prayagupd/.mozilla/firefox/kmsa14n9.default/webapps
```

Apparently, it not the second one.

Answer (score 0):

These are some of the key tomcat directories:

- `/bin` - Startup, shutdown, and other scripts. The *.sh files (for Unix systems) are functional duplicates of the *.bat files (for Windows systems). Since the Win32 command-line lacks certain functionality, there are some additional files in here.
- `/conf` - Configuration files and related DTDs. The most important file in here is server.xml. It is the main configuration file for the container.
- `/logs` - Log files are here by default.
- `/webapps` - This is where your webapps go.

You may check where there are by the following commands:

```
dpkg -L tomcat7
dpkg -L tomcat7-common
```

Change `tomcat7` to your appropriate package name. By default for Tomcat7 it's usually `/usr/share/tomcat7`.