# How to solve "Error running Tomcat server(Ubuntu): Port out of Range problem." problem?

Tags: server, java, configuration, 19.04, tomcat

I am trying practice Java servlet where I need Tomcat server. I choose IntelliJ as my IDE which is throwing me popup message:

[image: Screensot of the pop error message by Intellji.]

I used this configuration:
[image: Screenshot image of IntelliJ Tomcat Local server configuration.]

And [this](https://pastebin.com/e30xmxbC) is what's inside Tomcat's server.xml file, where u can see the port number also matches with the one within IntelliJ.
But the port numbers of JMX, HTTPS & AJP is not mentioned in this server file by default.

Now the main question is why IntelliJ is responding like this when everything 'looks' fine? *Help me if u delt with this issue.*

Comment: In the Tomcat Server Settings in your screenshot there are two ports that are not assigned any value. What happens if you give them a port number?

Comment: @TomášPospíšek no changing port number in Intellij won't do anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside your Tomcat installation folder, go to
"`server.xml`" (probably [under `/usr/share/tomcat{x}/conf/`](https://askubuntu.com/a/145777/349837)) file and change:

```
<Server port="-1" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
```

to

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
```

As mentioned by of in [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-212545#focus=streamItem-27-3492422.0-0) Jetbrains issue tacker page.

Another important thing is: In the Deployment section, make sure to add Artifact like this: 
[image: Screenshot of Tomcat Config page]

And again if u miss something, follow [this](https://www.mkyong.com/intellij/intellij-idea-run-debug-web-application-on-tomcat/) page. And if u are in deeper other problem then follow [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360004373580-Its-been-5-days-I-can-t-seems-to-run-Tomcat-9-0-16-on-IntelliJ-IDEA-Ultimate-2019-1-3-in-Ubuntu-19-04-because-of-this-error-message-) link where I discussed to solve Tomcat9 & IntelliJ 2019.1.3 integration in Ubuntu 19.04. It took me 5 days to resolve this issue.

Comment: @user889789 I don't what u did, but you will be missed. :-D